# Javascript create array of unique objects from object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an elasticsearch response ($scope.myval) that conatins 100 records of user details. Of these 100 records, I need a list of just the user names and a few other fields, of which I know that there are only 5 unique records.

What I am trying to do is create a new array of only unique objects.

```
var meta = [];

function checkExists (value){
    for (k = 0; k < meta.length ; k++){
        if( meta[k].LoginName == value.LoginName){
            console.log("matches")
        }
        else{
            meta.push({
                LoginName: value.LoginName,
            });
        }
    }
}

for (j = 0; j <$scope.myval.length ; j++){
    checkExists($scope.myval[j]._source)
}

console.log(meta);
```

However this doesn't appear to be working as meta is empty.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `for (k = 0; k < meta.length ` will never run.

Comment: You're starting with an empty array, and expecting to fill it using the length of that empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest editing your code so that "CheckExists" does exactly that, and if it doesn't exist, explicitly add it.

```
function checkExists (value){
    for (k = 0; k < meta.length ; k++){
        if( meta[k].LoginName == value.LoginName){
            console.log("matches")
            valueExists = true;
        }
    }
}

if (!valueExists){
     meta.push({
        LoginName: value.LoginName,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var makeArrayOfUniqueRecords = function (inputArray, fields) {

  var uniqueArray = [],
      mappedArray = inputArray.map(function (record) {

        var newRecord = {};

        fields.forEach(function (propertyName) {
          newRecord[propertyName] = record[propertyName];
        });

        return JSON.stringify(newRecord);

      });

  mappedArray.forEach(function (record) {
    if (uniqueArray.indexOf(record) === -1) {
      uniqueArray.push(record);  
    }
  });

  return uniqueArray.map(function (record) {return JSON.parse(record)});

}

console.log(
  makeArrayOfUniqueRecords([{a: 1, b: 2, c: 0}, {a: 2, b: 1, c: 2}, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 4}], ["a", "b"])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
let meta = new Set();

for (j = 0; j < $scope.myval.length; j++){
    let value = $scope.myval[j]._source;
    meta.add({LoginName: value.LoginName});
}

console.log(meta);
```

Set is object which keeps only unique keys, so you don't have to worry about check function. Also if you need only Array you can add one more loop after `for`, something like:

```
let metaArr = [];

for (let key in meta) metaArr.push(key);
```